# How to set ASP.Net MVC Routing parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a website with internationalization and what I want to do is to support URL with this format:

```
"{country}/{controller}/{action}"
```

How can I tell the routing engine that {country} should be set using a session variable?

Comment: Enquiry: If you are using the country in your route, why would you need to maintain it within session? You can use the route as a means of persisting the selected country through page requests thereby negating the need to use session to remember this.

Comment: If someone connect to localhost/ {controller} = "Home", {Action} = "Index". But for {country} if the user comes from an english speaking country {country} = "en", from a spanish speaking country "es", from a french speaking country "fr" and so on. I thought storing the {country} in a session variable to reuse it, but I'm open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a custom Controller Factory. Start with your route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", language = "tr", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new { language = @"(tr)|(en)" }
);
```

I handle the culture by overriding the `GetControllerInstance` method of `DefaultControllerFactory`. The example is below:

```
public class LocalizedControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory {

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) {

        //Get the {language} parameter in the RouteData

        string UILanguage;

        if (requestContext.RouteData.Values["language"] == null) {

            UILanguage = "tr";
        else 
            UILanguage = requestContext.RouteData.Values["language"].ToString();

        //Get the culture info of the language code
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(UILanguage);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    }

}
```

You can here get the value from session instead of hardcoding it as I did.

and register it on the Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start() {

    //...    
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
}
```